# Different ways to make "make clean" idempotent without suppressing errors or using rm -rf?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile project which generates 2 folders a build one and a deps one. I would like to be able to run make clean as many times as I want and the result would be to only delete the folders and the files in them the first time (idempotent make clean essentially).
Any subsequent time it wouldn't throw any errors, it would just do nothing.
Additionally because I accidentally deleted my home folder once by using rm -rf in a makefile, I would like to avoid using that as well.

I have tried various combinations of using rm -r, rm -f, rmdirs and/or adding a prefix (-) which will only suppress the errors. 
Additionally I know I can solve this by using something like the following

```
    if [-d "./build"]; then
        rm -r ./build
    fi
```

Do you guys have any other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Not a fan of *clean* targets, just tell users to delete the `build/` folder (I like your hygiene!).

`rm -f` is the correct solution. `-rf` with a folder is fine. If you are feeling paranoid, just protect yourself.

```
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -rf $(or ${build-dir},$(error $$build-dir does not exist))
```

Here, *make* will expand the recipe before giving it to the shell. If the expansion of `$build-dir` is empty, *make* will expand the `$(error …)` and will stop, issue the error message and an error, and not even get as far as running the `rm`.

If you really don't want to use `-f` with `rm`, then

```
    -rm -r ${build-dir}
```

will cause *make* to ignore any error, but is a bit noisy.

```
    rm -r ${build-dir} || :
```

will attempt to run the `rm`. If that succeeds then your task is done and *make* is happy. If the `rm` fails, the shell will run its built-in `:` command which simply returns success, and *make* is again happy.

Answer (score 0):

`find paths/ -delete` may be useful, although as written it will fail if paths don't exist. There are many options and it depends on exactly what you want to do.

But `rm -f` is by far the standard for simple removal.

Remember that you can use `|| [ $$? -eq 1 ]` or similar to suppress specific errors - note the doubled `$` for make's own quoting.

Another way of achieving idempotency is to rename things to temporary names and later either rename them into place or delete them, but I'm not sure if that's relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

> "because I accidentally deleted my home folder once by
>   using rm -rf, I'd like to avoid it"

Removing `rm -rf` doesn't actually make much sense, since it does exactly what you want. It's only your fear that you want to find different solution, but that would be dangerous as well :-)

I'd suggest to use `rm -rf` but very carefully. I was using it for *years* and nothing bad happened. My example of use in the Makefile:

```
lang_dir = lang
domain = messages

clean:
        rm -rf $(lang_dir) $(domain).pot tmp_err
```

How could you compromise that? There's no way. Be careful but do not irrationally fear `rm -rf` just because it is THE INFAMOUS `rm -rf` :-)

If you are super unsure, you might require a manual confirmation for recursive removal by adding option `-I`:

```
rm -rfI target1 target2 ...
```

From the `rm(1)` manual page:

```
-I     prompt once before removing more than three files, or when removing recursively.  
       Less intrusive than -i, while still giving protection against most mistakes
```

Comment: Well what you can do to compromise that (and what I think I did in my case) is a typo e.g. ```rm -rf $(lang_dri)``` with a combination of a `*` following  and then may RMS have mercy on your soul. Also I don't think the point of make clean is to use confirmation.

Comment: @Satrapes well, in that case, just be careful how you write down the `rm -rf` command. Shouldn't be a problem in Makefile should it. If you don't put things like `~` or `*`, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever solution you use, `rm -rf`, `if [ -d ... ]; then rm -r ...; fi`, `find ... -delete` etc. - you'll always have the same fundamental problem: if the thing you're trying to delete contains a variable dereference, and the variable is accidentally empty, you will delete the wrong directory.

So there's `rm -I` (which might not work on a build server), and also `rm --preserve-root`, and also `safe-rm`.

If you're paranoid, you could have a directory called e.g. `cleanups` which contains links to the directories you want to clean, and have your makefile have:

```
clean:
    rm -rf cleanups/*/*
    rmdir $(readlink cleanups/*)
```

In the `rm` call above, the first star finds the links, second deletes everything in these directories, NOT including files starting with `.` (i.e. hidden files).

The `rmdir` line removes these empty directories, if they are indeed empty, assuming there are no spaces in the link names.